# Programmatically querying my company's employee directory

Tags: .net, active-directory, exchange-server

My company is a Microsoft shop (Exchange, AD, etc.).

I'd like to do queries on our employee directory like:

```
Person person = directory.Lookup("jsmith");
string title = person.Fields("JobTitle");
Person manager = person.GetManager();
if (person.IsManager())
{
    Person[] subordinates = person.GetSubordinates();
}
```

Is there any easy way to do something like this? I intend to do it on an informal basis in scripts, not in shipping code.

Comment: Tread carefully, as sysadmins may take notice that you're informally org-charting your employer. It might raise eyebrows to say the least, even if you're doing this within your normal account permissions, and even if this information is available to you in a more manual, GUI fashion (e.g., Outlook). I wouldn't do this unless you had a *need* for the information.

Comment: There's a couple ways to look at that.  Unless you are impacting AD or WAN/LAN performance there really shouldn't be much reason for a SysAdmin to care.  Depending on the office politics they could scream something scary and complain or you could just tell them I'm a freakin developer and this is my job to write these queries / scripts.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really think it would be a performance issue. Org charts and/or employee directories are valuable to competitors and recruiters - some bigger companies wouldn't look lightly on such activity. Anyway, I wouldn't risk my job over it.

Comment: I spent two years in Continental Airlines as a developer embedded in an IT infrastructure team.  A lot of time was spent planning circuits and server locations and you could easily impact the network by pushing out software or doing queries with tools like BindView on workstations or servers.   There isn't always an OC12 connecting you to the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used this but it looks interesting:

[Linq to Active Directory](http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/)

The give an example:

```
var users = new DirectorySource<User>(ROOT, SearchScope.Subtree);
users.Log = Console.Out;

var res = from usr in users
          where usr.FirstName.StartsWith("B") && usr.Office == "2525"
          select new { Name = usr.FirstName + " " + usr.LastName, usr.Office, usr.LogonCount };

foreach (var u in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(u);
    u.Office = "5252";
    u.SetPassword(pwd);
}

users.Update();
```